# How can I list all of my aliases in `iex`?

Tags: elixir

Sometimes I forget what I've previously aliased via `alias` in an `iex` session.

I can check by simply entering the alias I want to use, e.g. `iex(314)> SomeName`, or the default for multi-part module names, but it'd be also be nice to see any other 'non-standard' aliases I've already setup.

Answer (score 4):

Run `__ENV__.aliases`:

```
iex(92)> __ENV__.aliases
[
  {Repo, SomeProject.Repo},
  {Customer, SomeProject.Customer},
  {Merchant, SomeProject.Merchant},
  {Util, SomeProject.Integration.Util}
]
```

More info:

- [Macro.Env — Elixir v1.9.2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.Env.html)